# JqueryUI tooltip: close after x seconds ONLY if user does not enter the tooltip area

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-ui, jquery-ui-tooltip

I'd like to have tooltips displaying html code, including links, like the tooltips in AdSense. I managed to display HTML, but when the mouse goes towards the link inside tooltip, the tooltip closes!

I would like to delay the tooltip closure for 1 second, and if the mouse enters the tooltip in this period (or returns to the original element), keep it open for as long as the mouse stays there.
The tooltip should close only when the mouse is out of both original element and tooltip for 1 second.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you can set the close property as below:

```
function (event, ui) {
  ui.tooltip.hover(
    function () {
      $(this).stop(true).fadeTo(400, 1);
      //.fadeIn("slow"); // doesn't work because of stop()
    },
    function () {
      $(this).fadeOut("400", function () {
        $(this).remove();
      })
  });
```

Here is a fiddle to help you: http://jsfiddle.net/4sSkc/

Hope this helps

Comment: In the jsfiddle example, the tooltip disappears after a short delay, but enough to be able to go with the mouse over it and prevent closure. Also the tooltip disappear very soon after leaving it, probably because the timeout (of 400) is related to entering the tooltip, not of leaving it. Try increasing the timeouts to 5000, wait 10 seconds before leaving the tooltip and you'll see what I mean.

Comment: Hey, I just include two new properties on this: show: 100, hide: 5000, check the fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/4sSkc/3/